# Internet Explorer Local Storage

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, local-storage

I have a application which works great on all browsers but IE. I am using the local database provided with HTML5. I need to store 3 attributes for the users of the application. I know in IE I can't use the database approach and I was thinking of using 3 arrays stored in local storage, one array for each attribute. Is there a better (and easier) way of doing this?

Thanks

For example, I want to store 1) destination 2) where they are from 3) date
So I was thinking I will store an array for destinations, an array fro from locations and an array for dates. Then using some id I can index the arrays and get the corresponding information.

Comment: Do you have some example code to show exactly what you are storing?

Comment: What versions of IE do you need to support?

Comment: I need to support IE 8 and IE 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need local storage, then you need local storage! Based on the information you describe, I think it's probably too heavy to use in a session cookie.

Check out [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg142799(v=vs.85).aspx). Be aware that only IE8+ supports this, so if you need to support other versions - you'll need to do some extra work.

I would personally enable localStorage where possible, then fall back to a round-trip to the server if the browser doesn't support it (and the data is definitely too much for cookies).

### Update RE Polyfills

Keep in mind that the polyfills suggested by [Rafael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1243806/rafael-motta) will fall back to cookies if the browser doesn't support localStorage etc. Be sure to test with a good spread of data, and keep in mind that it will be sending all that data with each request (which has it's own ramifications).

Comment: Re polyfills: some polyfills fall back to browser specific implementations (for example userData), not necessarily cookies.

Answer (score 1):

For IE, you can use a polyfill to simulate a native localStorage: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills

LocalStorage uses a key:value system. But you can save more than one data in one key, using JSON.Stringify & JSON.parse.

Answer (score 0):

localStorage in IE does not work with this url:
file:///P:/Dropbox/abc_web/ingrid8/ingrid.htm#car..

through network if it works:
file://pedrojelp/p/Dropbox/abc_web/ingrid8/ingrid.htm#car..

Comment: I don't understand this and don't think it answers the question, although maybe that's because I don't understand it. Can you clarify what you're saying?

Comment: Could you explain how this answers the question?